# On the Picard-Lindelöf theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem

$dy/dx = f(x,y) = √(x^2 +y^2)
, y(0) = 0 $.

Show that the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem ensures the existence and uniqueness of the solution in some rectangular domain $D = (|x − a| ≤ A, |y − b| ≤ B)$ and give the values
for $a, b$. Demonstrate that for any $B$ the value of $A$ ensuring that the Picard-Lindelöf
Theorem guarantees the existence and uniqueness cannot exceed unity, $A < 1$. Find for
which values of B the value of $A = 1/2$ is possible.

So I know that $f(x,y)$ needs to be continuous and therefore bounded (which it is, I think $|f(x,y)|≤ √((a+A)^2 + (b+B)^2)$, for all $(x,y)$ in $D$), and also that $∂f/∂y$ needs to be bounded everywhere in $D$. I do not understand what "give the values for $a,b$" means, and $∂f/∂y = y/√(x^2 +y^2)$ is not defined at $(0,0)$, so how can I prove that it is bounded close to that point? Please shed some light, I do  not have a firm grasp on the theorem yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several versions of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. In one variant one observes a global Lipschitz constant $L=1$ to conclude that all solutions are defined on $\Bbb R$. Here probably the most local version of the theorem is implied.

- Yes, $(a,b)=(0,0)$ follows from the initial condition.
- If you restrict your considerations to the disk of radius $R$, then functions with slope bounded by $R$ are contained in the double cone $|y|\le R|x|$. Your box has to intersect this double cone only on the left and right sides, which demands $B\ge RA$. And the box needs to be contained in the disk, $A^2+B^2\le R^2$.
- As $\bigl|\|(x,y)\|-\|(x,\bar y)\|\bigr|\le \|(x,y)-(x,\bar y)\|=|y-\bar y|$, the Lipschitz constant is $L=1$, without having to care for the singularities of the derivative.
- The contraction constant of the Picard iteration in the simple supremum norm is $q=LA=A$, so to get $q<1$ ...